# Test User creation in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, itunes

When i try to create a test user in my iTunes connect account I am getting an error like "There are one or more validation errors below.". I have filled all fields and there is no errors shown in the fields.

Comment: This is something that we cannot help you with, try it in another browser or something or contact Apple support

Answer (score 6):

Safari's web inspector is your friend here. Go to *Develop->Show Web Inspector*, then select the Network tab. Attempt to set up your new sandbox user. You should see a call highlighted in red - this is the HTTP resource that's hit during the attempted account creation. Click on that, and you should see the server response content, which should contain some more helpful details as a JSON payload – something like:

```js
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "afafaf-1334-49ae-aaaa-19303ab5b2c8",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
    "title" : "The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value",
    "detail" : "This email address is not available for use as an Apple ID.  You may already have an Apple ID associated with this address. Please try again or sign in using your existing Apple ID.",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/attributes/password"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
    "title" : "The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value",
    "detail" : "Individual can't have provisioning privilege.", I'm having this issue. Can you help to get rid from it.?

Comment: Are you trying to add an existing Apple ID? The message seems to be indicating that you are, and there are various reasons why that may not work. I'm not familiar with the specific error message that you mention. The safe, reliable approach is to use a brand new email address that's not yet associated with any Apple ID.